# no more address or address previously allocated by another server tftpd32

Tags: boot, local-area-network, tftp

I am getting error

```
Client requested address 0.0.0.70 [27/08 08:47:17.406]
no more address or address previously allocated by another server [27/08 08:47:17.406]
Rcvd DHCP inform Msg for IP 192.168.0.105, Mac BC:AE:C5:E3:2E:EC [27/08 08:47:40.946]
```

is there any tftpd32 alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Your DHCP server is either out of addresses, or is actually trying to allocate you an invalid address.  Either way, that needs to be solved on the DHCP server; there is nothing you can do from the client.

Also, please take a look at [how to ask questions here](https://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask).  This question is very... not a good question... which is severely limiting the help you'll be able to get.